# Button is resizing when app is run either in the simulator or on an actual device

Tags: ios, uibutton, resolution

So here is my problem:

I am building an iPhone app (not universal) for deployment on iOS 7.0. In my very first View Controller I have two buttons. Both buttons are set as "Custom" and just contain a text png I made in Illustrator as the image for the button. My first button works great. It has both the @2x version and the normal version in the Image.xcassets folder under its own icon name. My next button work exactly the same way, except with different text file. It was created the same way. It looks great inside the storyboard, but when I run my app on either a simulator or an actual device, the 2nd button resizes itself. I have no clue how to fix this.

So far I have tried cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, reinserting the image file, playing with the button properties inside of the storyboard, and turning OFF auto layout.

Here is a screenshot of the simulator running next to the storyboard view in Xcode:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: check the frame of the button in viewDidAppear if it's the one that you set or it is resized somehow/somewhere, you can check it with debugger or print it to log: NSLog(@"button: %@", _myButton);

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the **Attributes > View > Mode** on the second button may be set differently, but you mentioned you have tried adjusting setting. Try deleting the button that is not working, duplicating the one that is working and changing the image in the duplicate to the second image.

To be sure there is not something unusual going on with your image (can't really imagine what), have you tried using the image that is shrinking in the button that seems to be ok?

You can also click on the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset to Suggested Constraints" to see if that helps. You can also try clearing all constraints and resetting them via that same menu.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of setting constraints yet to see if that fixed it. It didn't... However, I did try copy/pasting the working button and changing the image, which made the old button mess up also, so it must be a problem with the image I am using. But I recreated the image in Illustrator using the working button file, exported the new one, and I still get the same response... Hmph